# Does not implement inherited abstract member in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, nscoder

My interface in the `ApiDefinition.cs` is like below.

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSCoding))]
interface LSMAInvitationDescription //: INSCoding
{
    [Export("encodeWithCoder:")]
    void EncodeTo(NSCoder encoder);
}
```

In my `LSMAInvitationDescription.g.cs` its like this.

```
    [Export ("encodeWithCoder:")]
    [BindingImpl (BindingImplOptions.GeneratedCode | BindingImplOptions.Optimizable)]
    public virtual void EncodeTo (NSCoder encoder)
    {
        if (encoder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("encoder");
        if (IsDirectBinding) {
            global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("encodeWithCoder:"), encoder.Handle);
        } else {
            global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr (this.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("encodeWithCoder:"), encoder.Handle);
        }
    }
```

But when I build my binding project, I am getting the following error.

> > Error   CS0534  'LSMAInvitationDescription' does not implement inherited
> >     abstract member
> >     'NSCoding.EncodeTo(NSCoder)'  SightCallBinding    D:\Folder\SightCallBinding\SightCallBinding\obj\Debug\ios\SightCallBinding  D:\Folder\SightCallBinding\SightCallBinding\obj\Debug\ios\SightCallBinding\LSMAInvitationDescription.g.cs   47  Active

Please help me.
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

[This](https://github.com/sightcall/iOS-UniversalSDK) is the library I'm trying to bind

Comment: Can you try override the EncodeTo method? [cs0534](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0534)

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I was able to resolve this by overriding :)

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT But having another issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018752/xamarin-ios-app-not-launching-on-the-device

Comment: OK, I will look into it later.